# Chrome showing non english characters as capital

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, fonts

I have a website in Slovak and in chrome some characters are shown as capital. When I run the website in firefox everything is ok.

> font-family: "Josefin Sans",sans-serif;

Why is chrome not being able to handle the characters but firefox can? Is there a solution other than changing the font?
The capital letter appear in words like: "dňa", "spoznáš" etc.

Here is a comparison:

Firefox:
[image: Firefox]

Chrome:
[image: Chrome]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see a fallback font not capital letters.

Obviously, the unicode range for slovak – latin extended – isn't loaded.

Check your CSS and add the missing `@font-face` rule

```css
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 200;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/josefinsans/v32/Qw3JZQNVED7rKGKxtqIqX5EUCGZ2dIn0FyA96fCTNIJRIyzoYV0.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-02AF, U+0304, U+0308, U+0329, U+1E00-1E9F, U+1EF2-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}

/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 200;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/josefinsans/v32/Qw3JZQNVED7rKGKxtqIqX5EUCGZ2dIn0FyA96fCTNIJRLSzo.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+0304, U+0308, U+0329, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

body{
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans',sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 200;
}
```

```html
<h3>Článok 26.</h3>
<p>1) Každý má právo na vzdelanie. Vzdelanie nech je bezplatné aspoň v začiatočných a základných stupňoch. Základné vzdelanie je povinné. Technické a odborné vzdelanie nech je všeobecne prístupné a vyššie vzdelanie má byť rovnako prístupné každému podľa jeho schopností.<br>
2) Vzdelanie má smerovať k plnému rozvoju ľudskej osobnosti a k posilneniu úcty k ľudským právam a základným slobodám. Má napomáhať k vzájomnému porozumeniu, snášanlivosti a priateľstvu medzi všetkými národmi a všetkými rasovými i náboženskými skupinami, ako aj k rozvoju činnosti Spojených národov pre zachovanie mieru.<br>
3) Rodičia majú prednostné právo voliť druh vzdelania pre svoje deti.<br>
</p>
```

Also, check your devtools network tab to see if the latin-ext font file is loaded.

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked but I also need to apply it to non italic text. I tried to search but I'm confused on how u got the url for the font and unicode range. I tried changing the font style but that did nothing except the italic text was "broken" again.

Comment: You can get the needed font-face rules via [google fonts UI ](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Josefin+Sans?query=josefin) and get a css URL: `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700` (all styles weights included) It will automatically include all unicode ranges